# How do I get comment to wrap in line in Codemirror

Tags: line, codemirror

[image: **enter image description here**]

[image]

I want for the Html comment to wrap in line while the line is wrapped (enter is pressed) as it shows in the image. Anyone know what should I do?

Comment: I think [this](https://codemirror.net/demo/indentwrap.html) what you are looking for.